# How do I install Signal Desktop

Tags: software-installation, applications

I followed the steps shown below, but Signal is not showing in my applications folder.

Steps to install on Linux

Open your terminal.

Confirm you have APT.

Enter the following three lines into your terminal.

wget --quiet --output-document - https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list

sudo apt install apt-transport-https && sudo apt update && sudo apt install signal-desktop

The instructions came from here:

https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/articles/214507138-How-do-I-install-Signal-Desktop-

Comment: ERRORS:E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain why your particular steps are failing to add the Signal app to the menu, but I can say that the following steps are what I use, and Signal is absolutely in my menu with elementary 0.4.1 Loki.

```
curl -s https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y signal-desktop
```

You can see the instructions in the "Signal for Debian based Linux" section on the bottom right of the Signal download page at: https://signal.org/download/

Comment: Unfortunately, command shows errors, as follows:
E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
E: The list of sources could not be read. bash: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]

Comment: If you check the contents of that file (`cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list`), it should only have one line, that being:

`deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main`

From that DOCTYPE error it looks like you have the wrong contents in the file. I suspect a network error has caused HTML to be written into the file. No idea how that happened.

Try and run the commands above one at a time in a terminal, rather than copying the entire block.